# Django CMS 3 Detect if I am facing 'structure' or 'content'

Tags: django-cms

Django CMS 3 has two modes: **structure** and **content**.
I need to **detect** if the user is using one or the other in order to apply specific css.
Is there a way to to this?

Comment: Shouldn't you just apply the same css to target both? If you load in your css, then change from content to structure, you can't reload a different css file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can detect the current mode via `request.toolbar.build_mode` and `request.toolbar.edit_mode` like this:

```
{% if request.toolbar.build_mode %}
    We're in structure mode!
{% elif request.toolbar.edit_mode %}
    We're in content mode !
{% else %}
    We're not in edit mode!
{% endif %}
```