# Django CMS – Show different content for users and guests in same template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I would like to have different content for users and guests in my home page's template using **Django 1.9** and **Django CMS 3.3.1**.

It could be acomplished by making subpages and showing the corresponding content in the ancestor based on authentication conditional, but that makes the page structure overly complicated.

Is there an easy way of adding these **placeholders** straight to the **template**?

**I have tried this:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        {% placeholder "guests" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% placeholder "authenticated" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% placeholder "content" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

But as I am authenticated when I'm editing the content, I cannot access the `guests` placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
{% block content %}
    {% if request.toolbar.build_mode or request.toolbar.edit_mode %}

        {% placeholder "guests" %}
        {% placeholder "authenticated" %}

    {% else %}

        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
            {% placeholder "guests" %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% placeholder "authenticated" %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

    {% placeholder "content" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have some experience with Django CMS but don't know if this will work. The idea is to check if we're in edit mode by inspecting corresponding request variables. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191037/django-cms-3-detect-if-i-am-facing-structure-or-content).

---

**Update by @V-Kopio:**

The answer given above works fine in practice but Django warns about dublicate placeholders. This can be avoided by combining the `if` and `else` blocks:

```
{% block content %}

    {% if not user.is_authenticated or request.toolbar.build_mode or request.toolbar.edit_mode %}
        {% placeholder "guests" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% placeholder "authenticated" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% placeholder "content" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Actual half was already gone. But still, many thanks.